# .htaccess - multiple rewrite rule for SEO purposes

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I'm just watching some HTML course and there is a part about creating Pretty URLs using .htaccess file. Given example looks like that:

```
RewriteRule offer-creating-web-pages offer.html
```

As it is said in the course, we should use words separated by "-" just so Google Search Engine can read and index them as, well, separate words. And it's good to use multiple words so our page can be indexed better. But for me URL like `http://example.com/offer-creating-web-pages` is rather not that pretty. I would rather like to have `http://example.com/offer`. Here comes my question.

If I will actually use "short Pretty URL" (like `/offer`) and replace all links on my page with "short Pretty URLs" addresses would my page be indexed as good as if I would use "long Pretty URLs" (like `/offer-creating-web-pages` just because of existing proper rules in .htaccess? If so, is there a difference between this:

```
RewriteRule offer-creating-web-pages offer.html
RewriteRule offer offer-creating-web pages
```

and this:

```
RewriteRule offer-creating-web-pages offer.html
RewriteRule offer offer.html
```

? If so, which one is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at this wrong. Both URLs are considered "pretty", they're not messy, they're simple and not complicated.

An example of a non-clean URL, would be like `example.com/id/person.php?person=john`

However, one of the most important things to Google (or any search engine in this matter) is that the URL & content is relevant.

So although `example.com/offer` is clean, it doesn't give any idea or relevance to what is actually on the page. What is the offer for? Is it an offering to Cthulhu? Is it an offer for a, I don't know, dishwasher? haha.

So the URL you've been advised to use: `example.com/offer-creating-web-pages` not only tells the person browsing, but it also tells Google - this is a web page that is offering services for web development.

So it's not only about the URL looking good, it needs to be relevant to the content that is on the page. I hope that helps.

Comment: I understand your response, but I think I have to clarify my question. I know that both of URLs in my example are considered to be pretty and I know that URL should tell more than one common word to be relevant for search engines. But I often see URLs like `example.com/offer` instead of `example.com/offer-creating-web-pages` or `example.com/offer-washing-car-services`. Does it mean that companies "sacrifices" SEO for having even "prettier" URL? Or maybe it is possible to have "prettier" URLs in hyperlinks and "less pretty" in htaccess just so it is SEOd only a bit?

Comment: Look at it this way, using a URL like `example.com/offer` tell us nothing, so it drives the wrong traffic, if someone searches 'offer' & 'computer' and come across your site, because offer was in the name, but it was an offer for cars, that is considered bad traffic and it does effect your SEO ranking. Your URLs need to be relevant to the content that is on the page. Yes, you can use `.htaccess` to mask the URLs and then internally rewrite it. But you'll have much better page rankings doing it correctly.

Comment: That answer covers everything I wanted to know, thank you.